# Errors from INSERT statement without a column list

Tags: datetime, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm trying to insert a date value into a table (MS Access 2016), among other values, using the following code:

```
public boolean insertar_alumno (Alumno alumno) {

    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String fecha = formato.format(alumno.getFechaNacimiento());
    System.out.println(fecha);

    String sql = "INSERT INTO Alumnos VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, alumno.getId());
        ps.setInt(2, alumno.getDNI());
        ps.setString(3, alumno.getNombre());
        ps.setDate(4, java.sql.Date.valueOf(fecha));
        ps.setString(5, alumno.getNivel());
        ps.setString(6, alumno.getCurso());
        ps.setString(7, alumno.getObservaciones());
        ps.executeUpdate();

        return true;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error en intersar_alumno.AlumnoDAO "+ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I'm constantly getting the error

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.3 data exception: invalid datetime format

I even tried fixing a string value "2018-12-31" into

```
ps.setDate(4, "2018-12-31");
```

but it won't work either.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Use the '/' and the format 'yyy/mm/dd' instead.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn’t work :/

Comment: ms-access also has a DateSerial(year,month,day), maybe your code could insert that as a string. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dateserial-function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503

Comment: Try changing your INSERT statement to specify the column names, e.g., `INSERT INTO Alumnos (colName1, colName2, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)`. It looks like you are (inadvertently) trying to insert a Text value into a Date/Time field.

Comment: Great! That worked 100% fine. I was messing up with the order of the columns. I had checked that before and thought I had it right, but editing the statement like this made the code get the data straight to the right column. Thanks a mill!

Answer (score 0):

Although most (if not all) SQL dialects support INSERT statements without a column list, e.g.,

```sql
INSERT INTO Company VALUES (?,?, ...)
```

it is generally considered to be bad practice; the column names should be listed explicitly:

```sql
INSERT INTO Company (CompanyName, Address, ...) VALUES (?,?, ...)
```

This is especially important with UCanAccess because the default column order (`;columnOrder=DATA`) is the order in which the columns were *created*, which is not necessarily the order in which they appear in the Access UI.

Example: We create a table named [Company]:

[image: Company1.png]

and when we run the code

```java
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Company");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
}
```

we get

```
CompanyID
CompanyName
Address
City
```

Then we find that we need a second "Address" line, so we add it to the middle of the table.

[image: Company2.png]

When we run the Java code again we see

```
CompanyID
CompanyName
Address
City
Address2
```

Notice that the column names are not in the same order as they appear in the Access UI.

To work around this issue we can specify `;columnOrder=DISPLAY` in the UCanAccess connection URL.

Comment: That’s a very useful comment! Thanks a million for this. Kind regards